# Predicting using pre-trained model in tf.keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

What is the difference between rescaling and not rescaling images for predicting using a tf.keras Resnet50 pre-trained on ImageNet?

Is it necessary? How much of an impact does it have on the predictions?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of code showing your two scenarios, rescaled and non-rescaled inputs, and how you're doing prediction with the model on those inputs?

Answer (score 0):

It is the difference between the model working as expected, and not working at all, usually if you do not apply the proper normalization that was applied to the training set, then the model performs weird, like always producing the same output, which is undesirable.

So always use the exact same scaling and normalization used to train a model.